# Complicated if-then-else statement

Tags: bash

So, I simplified this code. Every time it runs, `else` or `$msg4` is always executed. How do I change it so it only does `else` if the `$nick` part doesn't match?

```sh
if [ "$who" = "$nick1" ]
    then echo $msg1
fi   
if [ "$who" = "$nick2" ] 
    then echo $msg2
fi  
if [ "$who" = "$nick3" ] 
    then echo $msg3   
else $msg4 
fi
```

Comment: Please format your code for easier readability by prepending each line with 4 spaces. As to your question: Perhaps $who is never equal to one of `$nick1`, `$nick2` or `$nick3`.  Run you script with `bash -x` to see what is going on. BTW: You don't show us where you assign your variables.

Comment: In addition, the line `else $msg4` means that the variable `msg4` contains a command which is supposed to be executed. Did you really mean this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can read how Bash `if` statements work: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs

There you can see there is an `elif` which you should use to chain multiple if - else things together so that the final else is only executed if none of the `if` statements match. Result:

```sh
if [ "$who" = "$nick1" ]
then
    echo $msg1
elif [ "$who" = "$nick2" ]
then
    echo $msg2
elif [ "$who" = "$nick3" ]
then
    echo $msg3
else
    echo $msg4
fi
```

You can also write the `then` on the same line as `if` if you add a `;` before `then`:

```sh
if [ "$who" = "$nick1" ]; then
    echo $msg1
elif [ "$who" = "$nick2" ]; then
    echo $msg2
elif [ "$who" = "$nick3" ]; then
    echo $msg3
else
    echo $msg4
fi
```

This is often easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Use `case .. esac`

```
case "$who" in
"$nick1") echo "$msg1";;
"$nick2") echo "$msg2";;
"$nick3") echo "$msg3";;
*)        echo "$msg4";;
esac
```